# How to make carousel take entire width of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I downloaded a carousel code from the following link: view-source:http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/.

I managed to get it to work in a plain html page. However, when I copy/pasted the code into my page for my website, I have a gap on either side, i.e. the carousel is not take up the entire width of the page.

I have tried adding height: 100%, width 100% in my css but it doesn't do the trick.

My code which is below works fine in its own page but once added to other elements of the page, i.e. nav and text, that is when the spacing issue occurs.

```
<!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
         <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
         <div class="fill"><img src="images/index1.jpg" img class="img-responsive center-block" width = "100%"></div>
         <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>#bebrown</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
         <div class="fill"><img src="images/index1.jpg" img class="img-responsive center-block" width = "100%"></div>
         <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Caption 2</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
         <div class="fill"><img src="images/index1.jpg" img class="img-responsive center-block" width = "100%"></div>
         <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Caption 3</h2>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="icon-prev"></span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
   <span class="icon-next"></span>
   </a>
</header>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Is your website live? If yes please provide the link or please try to replicate the problem in `jsfiddle` because this is basically `CSS` issue..

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad. Here is the link http://www.brownmanclothing.com/indextest.html. Any feedback would be greatly helpful.

Comment: See you have `padding:30px` applied to body in `custom.css` **line No.7**.. Change it to `padding:0px` or just remove it.. Also you have wrapped your carousel in a `div` who has **inline style** with  `padding-left: 15px;` Remove this and everything works fine..

Comment: You're a genius Guruprasad! It worked! Thank you so much! Truly appreciate it!!!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Now when it gets to the third image, the carousel disappears, the browser is refreshing and then it comes back. Any idea why?

Comment: Because your first `div class=item` has some invalid `html` and `img src` is not set properly.. The browser isn't refreshing here..

Comment: I do not understand why you have `img` after `src` in every image? like `src="images/index1.jpg" img`

Comment: I see that you havent' closed `"` in your first `div` i.e `<div class="fill>` which is why it is creating invalid `html`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your document and the doctype is HTML5

```
  *{
     box-sizing: border-box;
     /*add the other browsers here too*/
   }

   html, body{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
   }
```

And then the obvious images to width:100% etc.

See the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMoOzb?editors=110)